# How about the work mechanism of kudzu in older RHEL version while the system is running ？

Tags: devices

It seems that the kudzu can only take effect for new devices while the system starts up ！  
For example, although we can run the kudzu to find the new devices online, such as disks, but in fact no any new devices would be found！  
So anyone could explain such work mechanism that only limited to the system boot？

Comment: Please amend title, to be a good summary of the question, and proof-read body to make it more clear.

Comment: I always disabled kudzu on old linux systems; kudzu would pull stunts like detecting a keyboard someone had left plugged in and then halt the boot process until someone could manually get to that system. No, thanks.